# Hapi - enabling CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, cors, hapi.js

I am writing BE application using Node JS and Hapi (v17). While the server is running and I try to call an endpoint using `POST` method I keep receiving an error message:

`Failed to load http://localhost:8001/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I wanted to enable `CORS` on the server site, but nothing works for me.

here is how I enable CORS on the server site:

```
const hapi = require('hapi')

const server = hapi.server({
    port: 8001,
    host: 'localhost',
    routes: { 
        cors: true
    } 
})
```

I was also trying to enable cors for the specific route but this also has no effect:

```
server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/login',
        config: {
            cors: {
                origin: ['*'],
                additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with']
            }
        },
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
            return User.login(request, reply)
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know what should I do to enable CORS and get rid of the problem?

Additionally, there is a screenshot from the browser's network tab:

[image]

EDIT:

I have added route that handles `OPTIONS` method and now I have another issue.

`Failed to load http://localhost:8001/login: Request header field access-control-allow-credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

And here is how things look like in the network tab:

[image]

Comment: _"preflight request"_ means an OPTIONS request (as also shown by your request screenshot). So you would need to setup a route config for that type of request.

Comment: Ok, I can define a new route that handles `OPTIONS` method but what should be the response fo such route?

Comment: Nothing, the content doesn't matter, the browser just looks at the headers to know if or not it is allowed to do an actual request

Comment: @PatrickEvans ok, I have prepared another route to handle this request and I receive another error. Please take a look at my edited post

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is a **response** header - so why is it in your `Access-Control-Request-Headers` request header - please show the client side code that is making the request - clearly you're putting response headers in the request

Comment: @JaromandaX good point. After removing this header from the request everything works correctly. Thanks, guys.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue, can you please paste your client-side code how you are calling REST service. In my case am using Angular 6 code!

Answer (score 1):

```
cors: {
            origin: [
                '*'
            ],
            headers: ["Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "If-None-Match", "Accept-language"],
            additionalHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, x-ms-request-id , Authorization"],
            credentials: true
        }
```

You should also probably define a qualified domain, instead of just * wildcard